# UITableViewCell custom view but reusable

Tags: swift, uitableview, user-interface

i am experiencing problems with my UITableView. I am using custom cells, which have a subview with a dropdown menu. But since cells are reusable, once one of my custom cell's subviews is "dropped down", the next reused cell is also "dropped down", messing up the cell height and the subview.

Is it possible to reuse cells and to keep the cells frame for the original cell but also have the reused cell not being "dropped down"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean up before the cell is sent to the tableview in the [prepareForReuse](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse) in the tableviewcell

Comment: Thank you CJay. That already helped a lot. But i am still having problems regarding the cell height of the original cell. I did describe this issue in the comment below Evgeny's answer. 
Is it possible to reset the cell's height in prepareFor
Reuse?

Comment: Add this to your `viewDidLoad()` 

`tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and
`tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0`
check out 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html

Comment: Thank you cjay. Unfortunately the problem remains :(

Comment: I was able to fix this. The problem was, that i was holding the indexPath for the cell in an array for the "dropped down" cells.
I checked this array in heightForRowAtIndexPath and calculated the desired height. I forgot to remove the cell from this array. 
Now i was able to accomplish this  in didEndDisplayingCell.
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Cool, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

In your UITableViewCell subclass you should override `prepeareForReuse` method(ObjC)/function(Swift) - to turn off cell `drop down` mode.

Swift:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    //set cell to initial state here - turn off drop down mode
}
```

Objective-C:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];

    //set cell to initial state here - turn off drop down mode
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I managed to reset the dropdown and redraw the subview in prepareForReuse. But i still have the problem that the original cell keeps the wrong height once it was dropped down. To make the cell grow with the subview when the subview is dropped down i am using a delegate and tableView.beginUpdates() and tableView.endUpdates().
Is there anyway to reset the original cell's height in prepareForReuse?

Comment: Th problem is solved. I forgot to remove the indexPath of the cell from an array in which i stored the "dropped down" cell's indexPathes to calculate their height in heightForRowAtIndexPath. Now i'm removing the indexPath from the array in didEndDisplayingCell. Thank you for your help Evgeny.

Comment: You may try to add `isExpanded` bool property to your cell, to be able manage expanded or not cell state. If cell is expanded it will be true, and vice versa. So in your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` get your cell by index path, check cell for `isExpanded` - and return required height.

Comment: Congrats @weka1 ;)